# (beginner) How to dynamically modify a json file

Tags: javascript, php, json

First of all, sorry for my bad english and my dirty code. I tried to create a base file to show what I would like to do.

Goal: I would like to create a simple web page in which it would be possible to modify the style of a div and save everything in a json file so that we can retrieve the changes during a future opening of the file.

Content of the json file:

```
{
  "width": 100,
  "height": 100
}
```

I managed to read my json file with PHP and edit it with form inputs but the page is refreshed with each modification. It's not very optimal.

```html
<!-- Json r/w -->
<?php
$file = file_get_contents("data.json");
$json = json_decode($file, true);

if(isset($_POST)) {
    if($_POST['width'] != '') { 
        $json['width'] = $_POST['width'];
    }
    if($_POST['height'] != '') {    
        $json['height'] = $_POST['height'];
  }
  file_put_contents("data.json", json_encode($json));
}
?>

<!-- Datas infos -->
<p>
$file = <?= $file ?><br/>
$json = <?= $json ?><br/>
$width = <?= $json['width']; ?><br/>
$height = <?= $json['height']; ?>
</p>

<!-- Form -->
<form action="" method="post" id="form">
  <input type="range" name="width" min="0" max="100" value="<?= $json['width']; ?>" step="10" onchange="submit()"><br/>
  <input type="range" name="height" min="0" max="100" value="<?= $json['height']; ?>" step="10" onchange="submit()">
</form>

<!-- The stylized div -->
<div style="background: #000; width: <?= $json['width'];?>px; height: <?= $json['height'];?>px">
</div>
```

Is it possible to reproduce a similar result with a better technique?
Using ajax or something else ? Avoid page refresh ? I get lost in the forums looking for an answer...

To be sure: is it necessary to use a form and php to modify the contents of a local json file?

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: I would suggest looking at something like jsonnet. It's programmable JSON, so may do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer gjones. My problem is very basic and jsonnet seams to be a little bit complexe for my situation. To be honnest, I can't understand clearly what it is... I do not have much knowledge in web development and I would like to limit myself to basic languages and technologies.

Answer (score 1):

For the change to be applied without a page reload, you will need to avoid form submissions. Use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to send your data to the server -- which will then save it to the JSON file and/or respond back with the existing JSON. To do this, you'll want to split your code into two parts -- the server-side part which will read/update the JSON file, and the client-side part which will be pure HTML and will send the requests to the server on field changes.

Comment: Do you have a good example that would help me understand how to do this? I only find answers from people using jQuery or who just read the json. I'm a beginner front-end dev, the server side is very confusing to me.